# Save changes function not properly updating the database

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, entity-framework

So, I have a button that triggers a javascript function, that calls an AJAX request, that calls an actionresult that should update my database.

**Javascript Call**

```js
function changeDepartment() {

    // Initiate and value variables,
    var id = $('#requestId').val();
    var user = $('#contactUser').val();
    // Bind variables to data object
    var data = { id: id }
    // Ajax call with data.
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("changeDepartmentActionResult", "ManageRequestResearch")',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {

            var name = data.name;

            window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "ManageRequestResearch")';
            $('#btn-input').val('');
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("responseText: " + jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    });
alert(data);
```

And then, I have the action result:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult changeDepartmentActionResult(string id)
{
    var moadEntities = new MOADEntities();
    moadEntities.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    var researchBusiness = new ResearchRequestBusiness(moadEntities);
    var request = researchBusiness.FetchRequestById(Convert.ToInt32(id));

    var directoryObject = GetActiveDirectoryObject(request.Requestor);
    var requstorDisplayName = directoryObject != null ? directoryObject.DisplayName : request.RequestorFullName;
    var researchRequestFileBusiness = new ResearchRequestFilesBusiness(moadEntities);
    var requestFiles = researchRequestFileBusiness.FetchFilesByRequestId(Convert.ToInt32(id));

    var viewModel = new ManageSelectedRequestResearchViewModel()
    {
        RequestDetails = request,
        RequestActivity = request.tbl_ResearchRequestActivity.Select(d => d).ToList(),
        Files = requestFiles
    };

    moadEntities.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;


    if (request.GovernmentEnrollment == true)
    {
        request.GovernmentEnrollment = false;
        request.ManagedCare = true;
        moadEntities.SaveChanges();
    }
    else
    {
        request.ManagedCare = false;
        request.GovernmentEnrollment = true;
        moadEntities.SaveChanges();
    }

    return Json("Status changed successfully", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

From what I have observed, it returns the right record, it makes the changes properly, and it hits the Context.SaveChanges();
when debugging -- i can see before the save changes is made that the values have indeed changed, however--inside the database, no changes are saved.

In addition, i have checked to see that the connection strings are valid.

Any idea what may be causing this?
Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: 1. "i can see before the save changes is made that the values have indeed changed" where are you seing this?
2. In your changeDepartmentActionResult(string id) method it does not appear that you  have applied any new values to be saved?

Comment: Why do you disable AutoDetectChanges twice and never enable it again? What happens in an exception case? Also, what happens to the context instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are modifying an entity while auto detecting changes are disabled.

If it is intentional then you should inform the context that the entity has been changed.

I assume that `MOADEntities` is derived from `DbContext`. So instead of this:

```cs
if (request.GovernmentEnrollment == true)
{
    request.GovernmentEnrollment = false;
    request.ManagedCare = true;
    moadEntities.SaveChanges();
}
else
{
    request.ManagedCare = false;
    request.GovernmentEnrollment = true;
    moadEntities.SaveChanges();
}
```

I would try this:

```cs
// Simplify the if..else block
request.ManagedCare = request.GovernmentEnrollment;
request.GovernmentEnrollment = !request.GovernmentEnrollment;

// Notifying the context that the 'request' entity has been modified.
// EntityState enum is under System.Data.Entity namespace
moadEntities.Entry(request).State = EntityState.Modified;

// Now we can save the changes.
moadEntities.SaveChanges();
```